# VS2013 How To Create a Solution after Cloning Git

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013

I have cloned a MVC project from my Visual Studio Online (git) onto my laptop. How do I create a solution for the project so I can actually open it.

I'm sure I'm being doubt and missing something obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you have the project file (csproj or vbproj), you could simply create a new project of the right type which will handle the creation of the solution file, then add your existing project (right-click on the solution) and delete the default project it created